# Python os.walk: how to delete directories after its sub-directories are all deleted

Tags: directory, delete-file, os.walk

I have a multi-layer directory. I want to start from the lowest level directories and delete all empty directories. My current code doesn't delete higher-level directories that become empty after their sub-directories are all deleted becuase os.walk supposedly doesn't update the path? How should I modify it so that it updates `root` each time?

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(starting_directory, topdown=False):
    if not files and not dirs:
        shutil.rmtree(root)
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will do the job.  Goes to the very bottom of a directory tree... is the directory empty? yes? then delete and goes up from there.  Good for cleaning empty folders.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
*
*  This python script removes empty directories using a bottom-up approach.
*  It can be run from your present directory and it will remove all directories that are 
*  completely empty - working from the lowest levels -- up to your present directory.
"""

import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:
        print("...in for name in dirs", name)
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
        if len(os.listdir(os.path.join(root, name))) == 0:
            print("Directory is empty... deleting")
            os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, name))
        else:    
            print("Directory is not empty")
```